# Change in behavior in HttpContext.Current in MVC5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application that has critical functions that change based on deployment environment.

Things like SQL strings, etc...

I have for weeks been relying on a method that reads information from the HttpContext, and sets an enum which triggers a series of other events.

Recently, and I cannot find what we changed that made this happen, `GetLocation()` always returns 127.0.0.1 on all three environments.

Additionally, `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent` is always null, though the parent object `Request` is not.

What might I have changed to have made this happen?

```
private static string GetLocation()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
}

private DeploymentType GetCurrentDeploymentType()
{
    switch (Location)
    {
        case "localhost":
            return DeploymentType.Sandbox;
        case "ppe.host.net":
            return DeploymentType.PPE;
        case "prod.com":
            return DeploymentType.Production;
        default:
            return DeploymentType.Sandbox;
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION / MORE INFORMATION**

We're on the right track here, but there's some funny behavior going on.

The methods you see above exist inside a Lazy Singleton that follows Jon Skeet's great pattern here:

[REFERENCE: Lazy Singleton from C# in depth, 3rd edition](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

This was perfect, as the object did not get instantiated until it was called in the Home Controller, and therefore the `HttpContext` was established.

Well, it seems we added a reference to the object in the `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` of the Startup.Auth.cs.

This was intentional, as we wanted to assign the proper ClientId for our app's deployment location, which is dependant on an OAuth2 flow.

It seems we need to rethink our design pattern.

Closing this shortly unless someone wants to add input.

Comment: Stop automated test that run against your local box - or fix them to provide valid host/user agent.

Comment: do not depend on `HttpContext` in your application layer. It's easy to get it wrong as you have noticed.

Comment: @jgauffin What is the better pattern? Is there a way to get the URL at this point in the application?